# Creating multiple time-series objects from a single data.frame with categoric variables as columns and dates as rows

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data.frame as below. The rownames identify dates, the column names identify a categoric variable (account).

I would like to create a separate time series object for each categoric variable keeping in mind that the number of categoric variables can vary (right now I have 5, but I could have 7, 8, 9, etc...) and the start and end date can vary (right now each categoric variable spans the entire time period but that may not always be the case).

I have tried `if` loops and `tapply()` with no success. I can manually acheive the results I want, but I am attempting to design something that is scalable for arbitary numbers of categoric variables and dates, i.e. irrespective of the size/span of each.

```
       A  B  C   D   E
14975 130 23  1   5  53
15006 125 22  3   8  45
15034 112 20  4   6  44
15065 110 21  2   7  48
15095 122 53 10  17  60
15126 133 42 12  18  65
15156 121 46  9  16  59
15187 127 47 11  19  63
15218  95 24 13  46  66
15248 105 29 14  35  61
15279  93 25 15  33  61
15309 107 64 35 149  62
15340  81 55 26 131  67
15371  80 43 36 134  71
15400  88 49 41 130  86
15431  95 51 40 132  86
15461  87 48 39 135  90
15492 103 57 33 139  97
15522 108 58 38 129  97
15553 109 71 32 138  92
15584 104 68 34 126  84
15614 102 70 37 123  75
15645  97 68 39 124  76
15675 117 90 56 136  99
15706 111 89 30 140  96
15737 119 94 28 140  98
15765 128 97 31 137  98
15796 129 79 27 143 106
15826 113 74 50 146 100
15857 118 85 53 142  98
15887 120 85 50 145  91
15918 113 77 52 141 101
15949 115 74 55 144  95
15979 115 83 54 148  73
16010 116 78 47 147  72
16040 114 82 56 150  69
```

Comment: could you give a small example of what you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In base graphics, a for loop will accomplish what you describe.  Here's some data:

```
A<-round(rnorm(50,100,5))
B<-round(rnorm(50,10,5))
C<-round(rnorm(50,50,5))
t<-round(seq(1400,1500,length.out=50))
dat<-cbind(A,B,C)
```

Set up a plot:

```
plot(t,A,ylim=c(0,150),type="n")
```

Add lines:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dat){
ts=lines(t,dat[,i])
}
```